# For a JVM app, is there any good reason to use Elasticsearch REST API?

Tags: java, rest, elasticsearch, jvm, transport

I am working on a Java app using, among other things, Elasticsearch.

So far, I have used a Java node client. Then some time ago I heard from some colleagues that the REST API is preferred, for the following reasons:

1. Being able to upgrade Elasticsearch without bumping the transport client version, i.e. the Java client's version is dependent on what version is the ES cluster running
2. Node/transport clients will be deprecated in the upcoming releases?
3. Security

I am now trying to find out how much this holds.

When it comes to #1, [the Elasticsearch docs state](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html) that it's (usually) enough that the client and the ES cluster are of the same major version. So, REST API doesn't really provide something better here.

Then, #3 is being handled by [Shield](https://www.elastic.co/products/shield).

I could not find anything about #2.

From the info above, the only reason for which I might want to use the REST API in my Java app is the version independence, just to be on the safe side. Other than that, not much; is that actually true? And is it true that the node/transport client will be deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an ES expert but we are just asking ourselves the same questions and here are our thoughts on the subject.

1. ES client version vs. ES server version :

   - Native client follow the rules you stated: major version compatibility. It was not the case until recently and for really specific features (Percolator for instance), this is still not (breaking changes on minor versions),
   - It seems Jest, the best HTTP client abstraction now, has the same constraints: [documentation](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest#compatibility) says version 1.x doesn't work with 2.x,
   - Last solution would be to use a low level HTTP client but with the lose of nice fluent Java abstractions. It doesn't stand the comparison,
   - You cannot address mixed version of ES with a Java app based on native client (in case of heterogeneous environments with both 1.x and 2.x instances). It should be possible with HTTP client and thus can ease some progressive migration scenario for instance.
2. Native client deprecation :

   - It's not clearly stated, but [there will be an official HTTP client for version 5.x](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7743). With that, what will be the point of having two clients?
3. Security :

   - basic HTTP security is easy to setup with some middleware if needed (Apache frontend for instance) or using https://github.com/Asquera/elasticsearch-http-basic,
   - Shield is official, works with both native and HTTP but not free…

In our app, we are using Spring Data ES. Very easy to use, with very few lines of code, but suffers from version lagging (support for 2.x 6 months after release of ES 2) and is based on native client. From our point of view, the tradeoffs worth the gain in development efficiency.

Last, SAAS offers only provide HTTP API, so in this case, you haven't the choice.

Comment: 5.0 Alpha is already there, so right now, and based on your feedback amongst others, it seems to me as the best idea to stick with the node client, until ES has their own HTTP client. Then it will be easier to decide.: ) Thanks a lot!